# Cómo convertir un sitio HTML - Bootstrap - JS en un proyecto NodeJS o React?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs, bootstrap

Tengo un proyecto muy sencillo creado con HTML, Bootstrap y algunas funciones en JavaScript. Ahora necesito transformarlo en un proyecto NodeJS o React, pero no he hallado cómo puedo hacerlo. Debo crear un proyecto nuevo de este tipo e importar lo que tengo? Cómo lo hago?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: como para que dices que "necesitas" convertir tu sitio?

Comment: Quizas convertirlo a React... pero a NodeJS? Node corre de lado del servidor, segun lo que dices, todo lo que tu tienes está de lado del cliente... para eso si te funcionaría React... aunque... la misma pregunta... para que requieres convertirlo? En caso de definitivamente querer "convertir" tu proyecto a React, no hay una manera mágica de "importar" nada... debes desarrollarlo en la nueva tecnología. Obvio ya tienes una base sobre la cual construir, pero la lógica de funcionamiento es distinta.

Comment: Lo primero que te recomiendo hacer es leer la documentación oficial de [React](https://es.reactjs.org/) para aprender cómo funciona.

Comment: Si solo tienes algunas funciones en Javascript React no va a agregar mucho valor. React esta diseñado para paginas primariamente dinámicas.